# Why doesn't this webm play?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have confusion because a webm isn't showing up properly. But when I change the code to the bare minimum like `<video controls><source src="http://i.imgur.com/91S22q6.webm" type="video/webm" codecs="vp8, vorbis" style="width: 100%; height: auto;></video>` then it works... so what is going on with my *full* code that the webm doesn't work?

https://jsfiddle.net/2buqa04d/

HTML

```
<div class = "entry-body">
  <div class = "entry-title">
    <a href="http://i.imgur.com/91S22q6.webm">Title</a>
  </div>
  <div class= "entry-byline">
    by John Smith
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.entry-body').each(function() {

var hplink = ($(this).find('.entry-title').find("a").prop('href'));

                        if (hplink.toLowerCase().match(/\.(webm)/g)) { 
                            
              
                            
            $(this).find('.entry-byline').after('<div class="beforeembed"></div><div class="hpembed hpembedMW"><video controls><source src="'+hplink+'" type="video/webm" codecs="vp8, vorbis" style="width: 100%; height: auto;></video></div>');

                        }
            
alert(hplink);

});
```

Comment: Did you inspect the element to check that the source src `hplink` isn't undefined

Comment: I'm not sure if JSFiddle has some weird problem with hyperlinks.
On my actual site when I do an `alert(hplink)` the correct URL shows in the alert popup. But when I inspect the element of the Video player, the HTML of it isn't filled correctly.
I think the hplink is defined.

Comment: When I change the JS code to explicitly have the WEBM url instead of hplink, aka change it to `source src="http://i.imgur.com/91S22q6.webm"`, it actually still does not show the webm properly.

Comment: If you copy the code `<video controls><source src="http://i.imgur.com/91S22q6.webm" type="video/webm" codecs="vp8, vorbis" style="width: 100%; height: auto;></video>` into a new jsfiddle does it play? Also in jsfiddle does that alert show up?

Comment: Yes. That works. So this https://jsfiddle.net/o96zr2bc/ works
But this https://jsfiddle.net/2buqa04d/1/ does not
And I do not know what difference is causing the failure.

Comment: Also does the jsfiddle code play in your computer?

Comment: Try adding hplink=hplink.toLowerCase() before you add the video and see what happens

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't work. If that works for you, can you please send a jsfiddle of it? I don't know if I'm messing up. https://jsfiddle.net/2buqa04d/3/

Comment: hi I'm on mobile so I can't but there is a quote missing at the end which night not cause problems in html but might in jQuery, try adding a coding " after the word "auto;" before the closing <

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is missing a `"` near the end

```
$('.entry-body').each(function() {

var hplink = ($(this).find('.entry-title').find("a").prop('href'));

                        if (hplink.toLowerCase().match(/\.(webm)/g)) { 
                            
              
                            
            $(this).find('.entry-byline').after('<div class="beforeembed"></div><div class="hpembed hpembedMW"><video controls><source src="'+hplink+'" type="video/webm" codecs="vp8, vorbis" style="width: 100%; height: auto;"></video></div>');

                        }
            
alert(hplink);

});
```

after "height: auto;"